# How would one delete any SQL row that is older than x amount of days while (column)Rank is x?

Tags: php, sql, rank

I have a rank system set up, where 5 is admin,4 lifetime donor, 3 is donor, and 2 is advertiser, 1 is user.
I cant figure out how to flush all rows that are:
-one week old if they are user (rank:1)
-two weeks old if they are advertiser (rank:2)
-2 months old if they are donor (rank:3)

While leaving all admins and lifetime donors in the table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to place a column in the table as value datetime and use following wuery to delete the record based on condition

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
`id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`rank` int(10) NOT NULL,
`timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 )  

DElETE 
FROM test
WHERE (week( `timestamp` ) >= 1 AND Rank = 1) 
  OR (week( `timestamp` ) >= 2  AND Rank = 2) 
  OR (week( `timestamp` ) >= 4  AND Rank = 3)
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this would do the trick:

```
DELETE 
FROM Test
WHERE (TestDate < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND Rank = 1) 
      OR (TestDate < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK AND Rank = 2) 
      OR (TestDate < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH AND Rank = 3)
```

havent tested yet. Before running this query to test that it deletes correct data instead of **DELETE** put **SELECT** and see which rows come up and then run this query.

```
SELECT * FROM Test 
WHERE (TestDate < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND Rank=1)
  OR (TestDate < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK AND Rank = 2)
  OR (TestDate < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH AND Rank = 3)
```

Comment: thanks ill let you know if it works but thanks for the fast response

Comment: SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE (regDate < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND user_level=1)
  OR (regDate < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK AND user_level = 2)
  OR (regDate < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH AND user_level = 3) 

That brought up an account that was recently created and is under one week old.  ?

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use three separate queries to query the database and delete the rows.

The first query - for rank 1 (User):

```
$query = "DELETE FROM table WHERE rank=1 AND time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-604800";
```

The second query - for rank 2 (Advertiser):

```
$query = "DELETE FROM table WHERE rank=2 AND time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-1209600";
```

The third query - for rank 3 (Donor):

```
$query = "DELETE FROM table WHERE rank=3 AND time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-2592000";
```

I hope that helped.